# Would a better antenna improve my wireless signal reception

Tags: antenna

I have a Verizon Wireless Home Fusion wireless system with a cantena antenna, however, living out in the woods reduces my receive signal strength. Would replacing the Cantena with a high gain yagi or log periodic help my reception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High gain antenna: set wifi router to single antenna or two](http://superuser.com/questions/328621/high-gain-antenna-set-wifi-router-to-single-antenna-or-two)

Comment: What do you expect to hear to such a vague question? "Generally, yes" is all I can say (and you probably knew this even before asking). You didn't even specify the wireless technology.

Comment: The most important part in radio communication is antenna, not amplifier or something else. If you get bad signal/noise ratio on input than amplifier wouldn't help. You need some experience to build antennas on such high frequency bands and appropriate tools to verify parameters of your DIY antenna. IMHO if you get parabolic 24dBi antenna it will cover your needs in case you know where to point it and there is straight line of sight  and  fresnel zone wouldn't be covered by trees

Comment: If you are not familiar with Verizon's Home Fusion technology, why bother to answer the question? Yes, a better antenna will generally improve signal reception, but are the antenna types I mentioned better than this so called "canteena" ?  Verizon technical support does not even know what I am talking about, and apparently you don't either.

Comment: @Allen If it's a specific technology (rather just a fancy name for a specific tariff/service), please add some reference links and/or info linking it to concepts closer to science. Not everyone lives in the US and/or cares about every piece of marketing blurb that's gonna be forgotten the next month.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, you not having an answer or a desire to give an answer does not mean there are not people who do have answers. Combative comments are not the best way to go about things. That said, while the question itself isn't particularly vague, the topic is. A superior antenna will improve signal propagation. The RIGHT antenna is a matter of the frequencies, the environment, and the protocols. 
And this question skirts topicality for this site, not for being a bad question, but for the chance it could have a better answer elsewhere.

Answer (score -3):

Wrap your antenna in tin foil, usually works. :P

Or better yet, wrap each of your antenna's (Assuming you have 2) with copper coil. That increases reception (i call this the redneck solution).

Buying a higher Gain Antenna is not going to help if the signal is still the same. The best bang for your buck is getting a repeater and setting it up half way.